# How to use Order by with Merge Statement?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

Hi am trying to do a merge statement where I need the items being inserted into `myTable` to be ordered by the 'index' of MergeFormFamilies table. Am I able to use a `order by` with a `Merge` statement? I can't figure out where to put the order by!

Thanks for your help!

```
MERGE myTable(childitem) 
    Using MergeFormFamilies order by [index]
    ON MergeFormFamilies.childItem = myTable.childitem 
When Matched Then 
    Update Set Childitem = MergeFormFamilies.childItem
When Not Matched Then 
INSERT (ChildItem) 
Values (Childitem)
```

I am using SQL Sever 2012

To clarify my question. I was able to do an `order by` with this `Select` statement from another part I am working on. How can I do something similar with this MERGE?

```
SELECT distinct Parent.Items.value('local-name(../.)', 'varchar(100)') [ParentItem],
Parent.Items.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') [ChildItem]
FROM dbo.FormResults
CROSS APPLY xmlformfields.nodes('/form/*')  as Parent(Items)
    order by [Index]
```

Comment: Tables don't have orders, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suppose your right... I have just been staring at this problem for way too long! I am new to SQL... I am trying to add a order by like you would in a SELECT/Insert Statement. Is there a way to do that with a MERGE?  (Hope that makes more sense)

Comment: @Gordon Nitpicking, but tables *do* have orders, governed by their respective clustered indexes.

Comment: @user Please explain what you are trying to do and why you think that `ORDER BY` would help you achieve that goal.

Comment: @Tomalak . . . The *table* doesn't have an ordering.  The clustered index does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A "clustered index" is nothing else as the physical order of the rows in a table. That's why there can only be one per table. That's also why insert/delete performance can suffer greatly if you choose the wrong fields for your clustered index in a large table - because big portions of data must be moved if you modify something in the middle.

Comment: With my select statement I am able to display my columns by their index - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
However, when I use merge they are out of order: 5,3,1,2,4 etc. How can I tell them to order by index?